# Show mobiscroll numpad in mobiscroll.prompt's input field

Tags: angular, ionic3, mobiscroll

I need to open numpad in mobiscroll prompt's input. I can't find any option in mobiscroll doc.

https://demo.mobiscroll.com/angular/alerts-notifications/alert#
https://demo.mobiscroll.com/angular/numpad#